# how to pass an array into an function and in the function count how many numbers are in a range?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;
    int calculate_total(int exam1[], int exam2[], int exam3[]); // function that calcualates grades to see how many 90,80,70,60

    int exam1[100];// array that can hold 100 numbers for 1st column
    int exam2[100];// array that can hold 100 numbers for 2nd column
    int exam3[100];// array that can hold 100 numbers for 3rd column 

// here i am passing an array into the function calcualate_total
    int calculate_total(exam1[],exam2[],exam3[])
    {
     int above90=0, above80=0, above70=0, above60=0;
     if((num<=90) && (num >=100))
     {
      above90++;
      {
       if((num<=80) && (num >=89))
       {
        above80++;
        {
         if((num<=70) && (num >=79))
         {
          above70++;
          {
           if((num<=60) && (num >=69))
           {
            above60++;
           }
          }
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: If you accept the answers to some of your questions you might get a better response.

Comment: Consider reducing the nested if statements, this makes the code flow quite hard to read.

Comment: 0 votes? Don't forget to vote on helpful answers, see the FAQ for more details.

Comment: What's the question?  BTW, all of your `if` statements will always be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a vector.
you can initialize a vector like an array.
the vector has a method to give you the number of elements

Comment: Guess vector is not the thing for this kind of homework, because using STL without knowing about plain pointers is crap

Comment: yep havent learned about vectors we are just on arrays in C++, im learning how to read a file into an array. i would love to see the syntex for this and see if i can figure it out from that

Comment: Inside the function call, at runtime, you only have a pointer, so there's no way to tell how many elements are in the array.  There's no definition at runtime.

The only thing that comes close is if you create a specific array type like this:

typedef int IntArr50[50];
declare your parameters as IntArr50
Then in the function do sizeof( IntArr50 / sizeof(int) ) to determine the size.  But that will always return 50 because you're deriving the info statically, from the type.

Other than that, there's just now ay to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using nested if.
Use if, else if and else.
Your program will be clean and will help others read better.

Looks like you are trying to create a frequency table.
Unfortunately, the code for the logic is wrong.
When you use `&&` AND 
It means it must satisfy both conditions.
How can a number be less **than or equal to 90** and **greater than or equal to a 100** at the same time?
May be what you are looking for is `||` which is OR.

And finally you need a **loop**.

Answer (score 1):

By the pointer to int array. (here is definition)

```
int calculate_total(int *exam1, int *exam2, int *exam3)
```

If you want call this function, you must in each argument push the address of examX array starting. If you want get element, you must add to the staring array address, a element offset address and get value from her.

Comment: The original prototype already declares a function taking `int*` - for parameters, the first dimension always decays.